# How can I prevent projectiles from being removed?

Tags: projectile

Sometimes a network mount point is temporarily unavailable. If I use projectile during these times, projectiles gets removed.

How can I prevent that?;)

Comment: What do you mean by "projectile gets removed" ?

Comment: As in, they disappear from the list shown when I issue helm-projectile-switch-project. This happens after projectiles that are on network mounted drives has been disconnected. By that, I mean, that sometimes SMB drives are not available, for example when a site goes down, so if I then try to list my projectiles, the ones on the disconnected drive gets removed from the list and they don't reappear when the site is back up.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not use `projectile`, but I will try to help.

The built-in package [`project`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Projects.html) (which I use) provides the function `project-remember-projects-under` to re-index projects. This function modifies the variable `project--list`. If `projectile` uses this built-in variable to hold the project list, then you can use this function to re-index your projects when you have to.

```
(setq network-project-dirs '("/one/path" "/another/path"))

(defun index-network-projects ()
  "Re-index projects located on the network."
    (dolist (dir network-project-dirs)
      (when (file-directory-p dir)
        ;; t is for recursive mode, it might not be needed
        (project-remember-projects-under dir t)))

(defun my-switch-project ()
  "Switch project."
  (interactive)
  (index-network-projects)
  (helm-projectile-switch-project))
```

If it does not, there might be a similar function that `projectile` uses. You can also add the network project to `projectile`'s project list manually in `index-network-projects`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this happens in the first place? Like, why are they removed? are they also removed with the built-in package "project"?

Comment: I guess `projectile` updates the project list on its own. Since it does not find the projects' directories, it considers them as dead. Every project I work on is on my computer so I cannot answer your question.